# como puedo borrar un base de datos en mysql que contine un - en el nombre

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

como puedo borrar una base de datos que contiene un guiontexto en negrita

mysql> drop database z80-b;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-b' at line 1
mysql>

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el nombre entre ``:

```
drop database `z80-b`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tenga caracteres con conflicto lo mejor es usar comilla simple

```html
drop database `z80-b`;
```

con eso evita errores

saludos!